# I want to reset Chat option (upper right corner of the screen)

Tags: empathy

I tampered with it and chose Yahoo Messenger and then didn't add any more options and now I want to add something else but I can't manage to find how. Is there a way to do it or I have to reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

you need to press F4 for a new account then a window will appear on the left will be a list of account and at the bottom a + - sign.  simply press the + to add an account and - to remove an account.  there is no need to reinstall ubuntu just because you have the wrong info in a chat account.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from scratch by deleting (or renaming) the `~/.config/Empathy` folder.

Comment: thats a bit extreme but works.  Why not use the GUI